# ver los datos por id de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

En una tabla con datos intento que me muestre los datos de una fila determinada por su id. pero siempre me muestra el mismo dato.
Os pongo el código por si vosotros me ayudáis y entiendo que es lo que no estoy haciendo correcto. El código que os pongo, ejecuta un modal que muestra la información de una fila de una tabla, pero siempre salen los datos de la última fila, aunque pinche en la primera o la tercera o la decimonovena.
Espero podáis ayudarme. Muchas gracias de antemano

Os pongo la tabla donde salen los datos y el modal para que muestre los datos de cada fila que como os digo, es siempre la misma fial, la última lo que muestra

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"id="mitabla" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 40px;">#</th>
            <th>Host Name </th>
            <th>Nº de Serie </th>
            <th>Modelo</th> 
            <th>Cargador</th>
            <th>Maletín</th>
            <th>Docking</th>
            <th>Ratón / Teclado</th>
            <th>Observaciones</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr> 
        <?php foreach($all_informatica as $infor): ?>
      
           <td class="text-center"><?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['hostName']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['nSerie']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['modelo']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['cargador']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['maletin']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['docking']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['ratonTeclado']))?></td>
           <td><?php echo remove_junk(ucwords($infor['notas']))?></td>
           <td><select class="form-control" name="usuario">
                      <option value="">Usuarios</option>
                    <?php  foreach ($all_users as $users): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo (int)$users['id']; ?>" <?php if($infor['user_id'] === $users['id']): echo "selected"; endif; ?> >
                       <?php echo remove_junk($users['name']); ?></option>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select></td>
             
           <td class="text-center">
             <div class="btn-group">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" value="<?php echo $infor['id'];?>" title="Ver">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
             </button>
        
                <a href="edit_informatica.php?id=<?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
               </a>
                <a href="delete_informatica.php?id=<?php echo (int)$infor['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" title="Eliminar">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </a>
                </div>
           </td>
          </tr>
           
        <?php endforeach;?>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   <div class="pull-left">
     <a href="export_informatica.php" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">Exportar PDF</a>
   </div>
    


    

  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                     
                    <h2><strong>Host Name portátil : </strong> <?php echo $infor['hostName']; ?> </h2>
                   
                    <table class="table table-bordered">

                            <tbody> 
                                    
                                    <tr>       
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Host Name</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['hostName']; ?></td>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Nº de Serie</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['nSerie']; ?></td>
                                            
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Modelo</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['modelo']; ?></td>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Cargador</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['cargador']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Maletín</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['maletin']; ?></td>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Docking</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['docking']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Ratón / Teclado</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['ratonTeclado']; ?></td>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Observaciones</th>
                                            <td><?php echo $infor['notas']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <th style="background-color: #f4f4f4;">Usuario</th>
                                            <td><select class="form-control" name="usuario">
                                                <option value="">Usuarios</option>
                                                    <?php  foreach ($all_users as $users): ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo (int)$users['id']; ?>" <?php if($infor['user_id'] === $users['id']): echo "selected"; endif; ?> >
                                                    <?php echo remove_junk($users['name']); ?></option>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                         
                            </tbody>
    </table>
               
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>      
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-print" onclick="javascript:imprSelec('nombre')" ><span class="fa fa-print"> </span>Imprimir</button>
        </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
     <!-- /.modal-dialog -->   
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-default -->
  </div>
 </div>     
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---AJAX--->
    <script >
         $(document).on("click",".btn-view", function(){
            id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url +"viewInformatica.php", 
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"html",
                data:{id:id},
                }).done(function(data) {
         $("#modal-default .modal-body").html(data);
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Falta (a mi parecer) más información; solo hay una variable `$infor` que llena filas de la tabla; no se aprecia donde la actualizas para saber que hay más filas con distintos datos a mostrarse. Espero haber sido claro en mi comentario.

Comment: He añadido el código de la tabla donde muestra los datos. Y modal que llama a que muestre los datos de cada fila, pero siempre muestra los mismos, la última fila

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Veo en tu código 2 `table`; uno con el `foreach($all_informatica as $infor)` y otro sin este; en lo personal no estoy familiarizado con esa sintaxis **`foreach(...)`**, **`:`**,  **`endforeach;`** por mi parte sería todo. (Años que no uso PHP).

Comment: Hola! Eso pasa porque el modal lo tienes fuera del foreach. Por ende solo se genera 1 modal para la última vez que el foreach reescribe la variable... Lo que puedes hacer es:
1. Mete el modal dentro del foreach y que genere un modal para cada dato de la tabla (en temas de recursos es mucho lo que se gasta, de preferencia NO lo hagas así).
2. Con AJAX manda a llamar la información de cada row de la tabla y asígnala a 1 solo modal.

Comment: He intentado seguir tu recomendación de utilizar AJAX para llamar la info (lo verás en el código) pero no entiendo muy bien que quieres decir con "asígnala a 1 solo modal". Hay algo que no hago bien....Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Falta el código completo, ya que no veo la función "remove_junk" definida, y tampoco veo que datos tiene $all_informatica.

Un saludo

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389560)